# How to install a windows service from windows installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-services, windows-installer

I am have created a service in visual studio using c#. I have added a ServiceProcessInstaller and a ServiceInstaller. However, I cannot get the service to install when the MSI is installed. Please help!

Using visual studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

Create Windows service project and designer mode of service (by default Service1.cs) right click Add Installer. this option adds ProjectInstaller.cs with 2 components ServiceProccessInstaller and ServiceInstaller.

Add setup project to create intaller

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should describe exactly all the steps you used. For example, simply adding the installer classes to your project will do nothing about installing the service. You must add the custom actions in the Custom Action view, adding your service to all the nodes in the tree.